# Compute the (Moore-Penrose) pseudo-inverse of a matrix in Python without NumPy

Tags: python, matrix-inverse

I'm looking for a simple python implementation of the algorithm without using libraries. The performance is not very important, just the logic behind it.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the source code of the function provided by the numpy: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L1890-L1979

Of course, in that file there are still numpy function used, so if you want to implement with no numpy at all, you have to implement every called functions in that file.

Hope I answered your question.